# How to get past forgotten password in fedora 13?

Tags: fedora, password

Its been more than 2 years since last accessing this system and I tried every password I thought it would be...

Is there any other username and password I could use?

Answer (score 3):

The generic Unix answer for how to reset a forgotten password is to log in as root and change it with `passwd username` (for some `username`).

If, for whatever reason, you can't remember the *root* password to do this, then you would have to boot the system into single-user mode (also sometimes called "rescue mode" in recent times).  You often have to have physical access to the machine to be able to do this.

Depending on what Unix you are running, booting into single-user mode is done differently.  On Fedora Linux, the way to access "rescue mode" is [described in the Fedora wiki documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_reset_a_root_password), but boils down to booting with the boot parameter `init=/bin/bash`, and using `passwd` from the shell that this gives you to change the root user's password.

After changing the root user's password, issue the command `touch /.autorelabel` to make sure the SELinux context is restored properly after reboot (please see the wiki link to read the full description of each step).

Then reboot and log in as root, change your ordinary user's password with `passwd username` and log out.

Comment: i think the autorelabel part is really important, otherwise Fedora breaks (selinux denials)